# Core Data: Relationships and User Objects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsfetchedresultscontroller, data-persistence

I'm using StackMob with CoreData (remote Database), but I think this is a general Core Data question.

I have 3 entities:

1. User (login)
2. Cars
3. Bikes

Each entity has several attributes.

A User can have multiple Cars and Bikes objects (to-many relationship).  Cars and Bikes can only have one owner (User) (inverse to-one relationship).

Now lets say we have 2,000 Users.  Each User is a car dealer and has 500 cars and 300 bikes records/objects stored in CoreData.  I would like the User to fetch based on attributes of Cars and Bikes.  I plan to use predicates for this.  To cut back on constant fetch request, I also plan to use Cache.

However, the questions I have  are:

1. How should I save the record/object under each User?  Is there a term for that in CoreData?
2. I would like the User to login and be able fetch all the Cars/Bikes based on its attributes (Model, Manufacture, DateStamp, etc.) only within the objects the User created.  I guess what I'm trying to avoid is when the User does a fetch request based on attributes in the Cars and Bikes entity, it only searches under its own User objects.  I don't want the fetch request to search through all the others User's objects because that would be a waste as I'm afraid that'll slow down the app.  What's the best way to set this up in CoreData?

Just went though 2 core data books and I'm not sure how to approach this.  I know I'm not the brightest so I turn to the experts for some advice.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this application distributed per user? If so, you just keep a local object graph of cars and bikes for the specific user (how you fetch information from the server is another matter).

Comment: Thanks.  User will need to eventually communicate with one and another i.e. to make offer on the Cars/Bikes and to check inventory.  Can I still accomplish that with keeping a local object graph?  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Also what happens when a user gets a new device and logs in for the first time.  How will he get the copy of the data?

Answer (score 2):

CoreData is actually really excelently optimized. What you need is an NSSearchPredicate and and NSFetchedResultsController. These are both kind of complicated and I can't just "tell" you how to use them. I found this open course to be EXTREMELY helpful

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

It builds a website fetching app in iOS using core data. Check the Core Data episode and if you don't know what he's talking about go back and watch some earlier ones